# Different behaviour of the background-url property in different browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am having a weird problem with the url of the background-image property in different browsers, for example my url is:

```
background: url("resources/images/icons/pdf.png") no-repeat;
```

In Google chrome doesn´t appears but in IE works.. but If I change the url by:

```
background: url("../images/icons/pdf.png") no-repeat;
```

In Chrome works but in IE not...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you trying to do this locally..

Comment: Locally it works, but from the server not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,in the CSS property you can add two different url for example:

```
background-image: url("resources/images/icons/excel.png"), url("../images/icons/excel.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Firefox supports relative paths in this tag but IE does not. IE is following the specs strictly. Try adding a forward slash

```
background: url("/resources/images/icons/pdf.png") no-repeat;
```

Comment: Sorry, but It doesn´t work... it tries to get the resource but it isn´t successful..  (404 not found in the console)

Comment: Is there a link i can see ?

Comment: I am sorry but it is not a public website.. :-(